# how do i check with SOQL if any objects in list fulfilling condition

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have this soql query

```
SELECT Id, Name, 
    (SELECT ContactPointAddress.Id, ContactPointAddress.IsDefault FROM ContactPointAddresses)
FROM Account
```

which list all contact point address for each account.
Can i somehow add a where clause so i can get the accounts that does not have any contact point address or where the list of contactpointaddresss dont have one where isDefeault = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["anti joins" (`NOT IN`)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm), like "*show me accounts that don't have any contacts, why do we even bother keeping them*" would be

```soql
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Account 
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
```

You can do similar thing in reports, [cross filter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_cross_filters_create.htm&type=5).

Try

```soql
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM ContactPointAddress WHERE IsDefault = true)
```

Comment: not sure i am getting the expected output including the last line, it returns nothing?

Comment: Does it compile OK? Maybe it has to be `ParentId`, not `AccountId`, I don't have an org with contact point data handy

Comment: your first query seem to list those that does not have any contact, I cannot get the where to work ?

Comment: 1st was an example for people that didn't work with contact points. It's a common requirement to show "accounts without contacts, accounts without any opportunities created last year"... What do you get with `SELECT Id, Name, 
    (SELECT ContactPointAddress.Id, ContactPointAddress.IsDefault FROM ContactPointAddresses)
FROM Account
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM ContactPointAddress WHERE IsDefault = true)`